# How to use an Angular input directive inside a component on every change

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I built a directive called `intellark`. It transforms QWERTY keys upon input into Arabic keys on the fly. It works fine. When using console.log inside the directive, every transformed letter is displayed, and the letters are transformed accordingly (type in English, transform and display in Arabic). I built it this way so that by adding the directive name `intellark` on any HTML input component, the input keys are transformed accordingly.

My problem is this. Unlike the behaviour in the directive's `keyPress()` method shown in the image below, when I added an HTML input component into the `app.component.html`, added it the directive `intellark`, 2-way binded it to `inputText` inside `app.component.ts`, the method `showIt()` isn't called on key input events. It did receive events upon pressing BACKSPACE however!

So, there is a disconnect somehow. How do I make the method `showIt()` listen to input events on the fly?

Although I could use techniques like services, EventEmitter, Subject and/or @Output to send the output to subscribing components, I am sure these are not the proper ways of going about this.

Any ideas how to register the input events with non-directive components? The image below shows all I built for this.

[image]

Comment: can you please try out way i sussggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you do like as below for you input box

```
 <input #box (keyup)="onKey(box.value)">
```

because by exposing `$event` at typscipt file .ts file you are exposing template at backend code .ts file which is bad practice , and make use of `keyup` , pass value of input box to you code `onKey` event.

Comment: Thank you! I love SoF because of people like you. It solved it! But, only on `keyup`, I tried it on `keypress` but it only worked when I typed, not when I BACKSPACed. Any idea why? The solution is perfect, I just want to know why.

Comment: @mohsenmadi - sorry cant help in that , i got to answer after reading things at : https://angular.io/guide/user-input ..angular site where they proposed this approach...may be for backspace you can write to angular team here : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues

Comment: Thank you! Definitely interested in learning more about that.